# Android Webview y Woocomerce (Descarga de PDF)

Tags: android, webview

¡Hola a todos!
Estoy tratando de incorporar a mi app una webview que cargue una web creada en wordpress y con woocomerce. En ella existe un botón de "Descargar factura", pero no consigo que el pdf que se genera se descarge en el dispositivo.

```
       myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
```

En el downloadlisterner consigo capturar cuando se inicia una llamada de descarga, pero al ser wordpress, la url no pertenece al fichero pdf por lo que no sé como acceder a él. Y el navegador de webview tampoco lanza ningún popup preguntando por descargar algún fichero.

Muchas gracias

Comment: A tu código le falta todo el evento, ¿Verdad?

Comment: Agrega más código crack.

Comment: El problema recae en que woocomerce genera el pdf en el momento y no otorga ninguna ruta para acceder a él. Si se abre desde navegador se inicia una descarga y chrome te pregunta donde guardarlo, pero desde la webview no pasa eso

Comment: Es que ese método debes crearlo tu si lo quieres ver en el WebView, no viene Default.

Comment: @osdward Pero la pagina de wordpress que cargo en la webview ya tiene su boton de descarga implementado y si lo abres en un navegar si efectua la descarga correctamente. ¿Porque en la weview no lo hace?

Tal vez no has entendido la pregunta crack

Comment: @ArvaOtero te recomiendo que te des un paseo por el link para que entiendas como funciona un WebView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView